# Another object on this page already uses ID 'XXXXXXX'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, controls

I am receiving a warning from Visual Studio 2010 that every single control in my ASP.net project has a duplicate ID. This is obviously not the case, since I named all hundred or so controls on the page myself, and I made sure not to allow any duplicates. Has anyone else run into this and found a fix?

Thanks

Comment: Any chance you made a copy of the page and did not change the class name?

Comment: An ASP.NET Webform with "hundred or so controls".

Answer (score 0):

restarting will work occasionally, but often the solution is to right click the "unrendered" control and select 'update'. This does the trick.