# "Another object on this page already uses ID 'XXXXXXX'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-multiselect

Not related to:
[Another object on this page already uses ID 'XXXXXXX'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626982/another-object-on-this-page-already-uses-id-xxxxxxx)

I've got a jQuery Multiselect `Listbox` control on my page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery("#UCStyle1 select").multiselect({
                header: true,
                height: 175,
                minWidth: 240,
                size: 3,
                classes: '',
                checkAllText: 'Check all',
                uncheckAllText: 'Uncheck all',
                noneSelectedText: '0 Selected',
                selectedText: '# selected',
                selectedList: 0,
                show: null,
                hide: null,
                autoOpen: false,
                multiple: true,
                position: {},
                appendTo: "body"
        });
});
```

It's referenced a bunch of times in div tags like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Looking for:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div id="UCStyle1">
            <asp:ListBox ID="MatchGender" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        State:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div id="UCStyle1">
            <asp:ListBox ID="sState" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, they need to reference that jQuery, but they're different controls.

I'm getting the warning:

> Another object on this page already uses ID 'ucstyle1'

Multiple times.

Any idea how I can clean this up so that I don't get that warning?  I think it's causing the page to look completely wonky on IE, but Firefox doesn't seem to care about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple divs with the same id applying css style works same like class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937756/multiple-divs-with-the-same-id-applying-css-style-works-same-like-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `div` tags with same `id` (`UCStyle1`) but since `id` is unique you cannot use a duplicate one in a page. You can use [`class`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp) instead of `id` if you want to repeat it.

```
<div class="UCStyle1">
```

And

```
<div class="UCStyle1">
```

And:

```
jQuery(".UCStyle1 select").multiselect({
```

Comment: Perfect.  Your edit was key; changing #UCStyle to .UCStyle as well as changing id to class.  Thanks!